# Are Mac OS images (eg. "OS X El Capitan.app") digitally signed? Safe to install from torrent?

Tags: digital-signature

So, I've upgraded OSX to Sierra, but I need to downgrade (long story), and OSX won't let me because I didn't create a Time Machine backup before upgrading.

So I have downloaded the `Install OS X El Capitan.app` image using BitTorrent.

I assume Apple are wise enough to digitally sign their OS images, such that this is safe. But I would like to know for certain before proceeding.

Comment: See  http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254720/download-el-capitan-installer-now-that-sierra-is-out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original macOS installer apps are not distributed as images (i.e. dmg files). So you won't find a digitally signed *macOS Installer.dmg*, dmg signing is possible though: [How to add codesigning to dmg file in mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23824815/how-to-add-codesigning-to-dmg-file-in-mac).

However, you can check the codesigning of the macOS/OS X Installer.app and the sha sum of the InstallESD.dmg (which contains the files which will be installed to your disk later):

```
codesign -dv --verbose=4 /Volumes/InstallMavericks/Install\ OS\ X\ Mavericks.app
```

and

```
shasum /Volumes/InstallMavericks/Install\ OS\ X\ Mavericks.app/Contents/SharedSupport/InstallESD.dmg
```

Compare the shasum result with the following list: [Apple Installer Checksums](https://github.com/notpeter/apple-installer-checksums/blob/master/readme.md). If the checksum is different the dmg is tampered.

The name of the mounted Mavericks.dmg (i.e. InstallMavericks) is just an example - so use the proper path to the macOS/OS X Installer.app.

Answer (score 0):

If you purchased/downloaded any version of Mac OS X from 10.7 to 10.11, you can always re-download it from the App Store on your computer.

After doing that, you can even create a bootable USB with the image.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question!

Comment: @klanomath Perhaps not the question as asked, but as the ultimate goal of the OP is to install a previous version of Mac OS X, I'm offering a suggestion to help them accomplish that, in case they didn't know about that.