# Purchase El Capitan after Sierra

Tags: macos, install, recovery

i've found a similar question but i think is a bit incomplete. I know how to download and install El Capitan now that Sierra is out. You just have to change the date in terminal to something like 2015 and the download will start. This is exactly what i did a month ago.
Now i'm having some random reboot caused by some sw (most likely Paragon and NTFS), but this is another story, so i would like to reinstall El Capitan.
I've done as usuale, booting into recovery and trying to reinstall El Capitan. After i put my credential in it said that "This item is temporary unavailable".

I got this Mac a month ago, so, of course i didn't purchased El Capitan since Sierra was already out. Moreover, if i have to be honest, i've purchased that, with the same account on a hackintosh, but of course, this is not working as planned.

And again, since this MBP is a 2012 retina that came with Mountain Lion, i've installed El Capitan changing the date in terminal, downloading it from Apple directly and now i have that installed but it's, again, not marked as purchased in my account.

So, i don't want to upgrade to Sierra right now, i would like to purchase El Capitan in 2017 to be able to reinstall it. I know how i can see the link in the store, but when i click "get" it says "impossible to complete purchase".

Any hint?

Comment: There's a hint on the El Capitan page on the App Store "This version of El Capitan can also be installed on Mac computers that are not compatible with Sierra". That would imply if it is compatible, & you don't have it in your purchase history, you're out of luck. Otherwise see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254720/download-el-capitan-installer-now-that-sierra-is-out?rq=1

Comment: [Make a full *bootable* backup of your computer](https://bombich.com) before you upgrade.  Then you can restore *everything* from the backup, including the OS.  (Also in your situation I'd recommend you keep an extra copy of the El Capitan installer.)

Comment: I could do a backup, the problem is that i want to reinstall El Capitan to fix some issue. If i do that, am i going to restore even corrupted files as well? Because otherwise is gonna be useless. I was also thinking about upgrading to Sierra if is the only solution but i prefer El Capitan for better stability since Sierra is not as stable from what i've read. @Wildcard

Comment: @Tetsujin Is this the same as reinstalling it from recovery?

Comment: From Recovery you will get the OS that was last on it [assuming you use the same credentials as was used to 'purchase' it in the first place. From Internet Recovery you will get the OS that was on it when it was new. There is no 3rd option without already having an installer on USB etc.

Comment: @Tetsujin Unfortunately i don't have any installer. I just upgrader Mountain lion changing the date in the terminal and downloading El Capitan from the store. After that i can't see the installer in my drive. My credential were always the same, here and on my hackintosh, but El Capitan is not under my "purchased" tab.
Btw, in recovery (standard command + R) i have the "reinstall El Capitan" option but after the login with the store it said that is not available

Comment: Installers go to Applications, called "Install [OS name]"

Comment: I think i've found that. I moved it on my dekstop. So, if i reinstall that from the  OS, is the same thing as "reinstall OSX" in the recovery? Am i going to lose my files and preferences? Because this random reboot is driving me nuts and i want to see if it's sw related or hw related, and the only option is to reinstall the same os i have now.