# How can I get the original Sierra installer now that High Sierra is out?

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, upgrade

I can’t find the installer and presume Apple deleted the Mac OS Sierra installer from the app store search as well as our collective purchased apps pages.

I'm running Sierra at the moment, and I upgraded from lion.

How can I get the previous Sierra installer now, in case my update to High Sierra goes wrong?

Comment: You may want to read Monomeeth's question at https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/286311/205310

Answer (score 2):

If you downloaded the Sierra installer before using your Apple ID, you should be able to download it again using the Purchases tab in the Mac App Store. If the installer does not show up in that list, [try downloading it directly from the Mac App Store](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/macos-sierra/id1127487414?ls=1&mt=12).

I do want to point out that it’s quite easy to reinstall macOS in case something goes wrong while updating. Just make sure you have a backup (e.g. with Time Machine) and you should be fine. In case something does go wrong, press and hold the power button to force you Mac to shutdown. Turn it on and immediately press and hold cmd + R until you see the Apple logo. You should now be able to reset your Mac from there.

Comment: The Sierra installer won't show up in the purchase tab unfortunately. And, external sites are known to sometimes distribute malware... If possible, I'm looking for a direct link to the installer on Apple servers. But maybe it's impossible and, in this case, I'll use your method

Comment: You may want to read Monomeeth's question at https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/286311/205310

Comment: The URL was missing the following parameters: ``?ls=1&mt=12``. I have added them now to the question's answer. The link should now open the Mac App Store as originally stated.

Answer (score 1):

Apple makes Sierra available even after High Sierra is released.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208202

The link to the installer on the Mac App Store is: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/macos-sierra/id1127487414?ls=1&mt=12

It's best to go to the article, though and check compatibility and an updated link if that comes out over time.