# How to downgrade to macOS Sierra without Time Machine

Tags: macos, high-sierra, downgrade

I upgraded to High Sierra a week ago, my MacBook Pro 2016 (15 inch) is very slow now even in normal daily usage.

I wanted to downgrade back to Sierra, but even tho my MacBook came originally with Sierra, I cannot find it in "App Store > Purchases", there is only Mavericks which I bought on my previous MacBook.

Is there any way I can download Sierra from Apple? Is there any other trustable source?

Or maybe I would see Sierra in App Store if I re-install "OS X Mavericks" again?

Comment: Generally, the most 'trusted source' will be Apple. Looks like you want to read [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/286311/251859).

Comment: You won’t be able to ‘downgrade’, even with Time Machine. Best you can do is wipe & start over. Manually move old docs etc via another drive.

Comment: @Tetsujin About "downgrade": is there any official guideline for wording this? I mean on this site, downgrade apparently meaning in-place with the installer *and* without wipe? Isn't "wipe and restart install with lower vers number"  always implied with Apple?

Comment: Even wipe & install won’t let you restore from Time Machine   This is the fun I had, even with multiple backup sources - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/271104/revert-to-el-capitan Frankly, it’s a nightmare, a clone is about your only chance.

Answer (score 1):

I got it from [this link](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/macos-sierra/id1127487414?ls=1&mt=12).

### IMPORTANT:

DO NOT downgrade using macOS Sierra (10.12 Installer) disk utility to Erase your disk, you HAVE TO use the Online Recovery tool (or High Sierra (10.13) Disk Utility) to Erase your disk from APFS back to HFS+ , then restart and use your macOS Sierra installer from USB.

If you use Sierra to Erase disk, you'll get stuck in a Reboot Loop which is what happened to me.