# Reinstallation mac os x el capitan

Tags: macos, install, disk-format

Is it possible to reinstall mac os x el capitan to a macbook pro (2009) using a bootable usb made in windows? The internal disk is already erased and empty.

Comment: Had you previously installed El Cap on this machine? Would you prefer to install High Sierra? It's possible with [this patcher.](http://dosdude1.com/highsierra/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you have a copy of the El Capitan DMG, see here if you don't. I also assume that your flash drive is empty - if it's not, **back up any files before you start as this will wipe everything from the drive**.

1. Insert your flash drive in to your computer and run Command Prompt as administrator.
2. Type `diskpart` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. Type `list disk` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
4. Locate your flash drive in the list and identify what number it is, then type `select disk X` (replace `X` with the number of your flash drive). Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to execute the command.
5. Type `clean` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
6. Type `convert GPT` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
7. Type `create partition primary` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Your flash drive is now clean and has a GPT format ready for use with a macOS disk image. Now you need to download and install [TransMac](http://www.acutesystems.com/scrtm.htm) (and use the trial).

Once TransMac is installed, follow these instructions:

1. Run TransMac as administrator.
2. Right-click your USB drive in the left pane and click <kbd>Restore with Disk Image</kbd>. Click <kbd>Yes</kbd> on the dialog box that opens.
3. Browse for your El Capitan DMG file and then click <kbd>OK</kbd> to write the image.
4. Now, wait - this process could take a long time.

Once the disk image is written and TransMac has completed the process, eject the disk and plug it in to your Mac.

To run the installer on your Mac, plug it in and hold down the <kbd>Option</kbd> key while you turn it on. Click the disk when prompted and run through the installer.

Comment: I don't have an El Capitan image file, I'm still searching for it

Comment: @NarutoUzumaki see this answer: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/263596/293729

Comment: Per the [link above](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/263596/293729), I would be very careful using anything from a BitTorrent site.  If the OS doesn't come directly from Apple, anyone could've changed the code to weaken the security.  Use good judgement, is all I'm saying.

Comment: i hold 'option' key but bootable disks aren't showing

Comment: @fsb thank you for the addition, yes it's certainly always important to check file hashes and such to ensure the image is genuine! (I would upvote your comment but it doesn't let me yet)

Comment: @NarutoUzumaki Turn the Mac off and start holding the Option key. Turn the machine on and keep holding the Option key until you hear the chime.

Comment: what is the circle sign with slash thru when i'm trying to boot to usb?

Comment: @NarutoUzumaki from [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/ht204156): `When you see a circle with a slash symbol instead of the Apple logo, it means your Mac couldn't find a valid System Folder to start up from.` This issue could also occur if you're trying to install an invalid version of macOS, for example if the OS version is too new for the system you're trying to install it on (this shouldn't be the case with El Capitan and a 2009 MacBook Pro, however). Where did you get the El Capitan disk image from?